is there a way to fetch text from an XHR named "ConnectExternal" in the network panel that appears after refreshing the page using python?
is there a way to automate
enter inspect element and then network and then copy the text that is written in a XHR  named "ConnectExternal" that appears when the page is refreshed using preferably python?
i didnt find a way to do this and im not that good in coding / python

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
